# Sub directory as root directory based on condition

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am in a bit trouble with htacess. Currently i have htacess in root -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

So whatever in URL it directly hit on index.php in root directory.

Now, I have a folder named "test".

Currently when i type http://example.com/test/ it hits on http://example.com/index.php but i want to when i will hit http://example.com/test/ it will hit http://example.com/test/index.php not the root directory.

That means when only /test/ on URL, i tried several solutions but none working!

In my localhost, i put root htacess in "test" folder and its working but not working in server.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by myself :D

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^test/ test/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```